How do I copy tasks between MS Project files with different Working Time Calendars?
I am attempting to copy one sub-contractor's programme into a master programme (two separate files) in MS Project. The two MS Project files have different working time calendars, with the Master version containing additional non-working time that the sub-contractor's version has missed (for example, they have missed some public holidays).
The issue I have is that when I copy the tasks into the master programme, it keeps the task durations but the end dates are extended due to the additional non-working time programmed in the Master version. This would usually be fine, however, in this case the sub-contractor's programme needs to exactly match the starts and ends of the programme they have supplied (for contractual reasons).
So my question is, is there a specific way to copy and paste the tasks into my master version whilst preserving the task start and end dates (as opposed to the task durations)?

Hi Sam. I need some info to write an answer to this question. First, how are you integrating the Subprojects together in the Master Project? are they "Linked" or "Unlinked"? See this article if you aren't sure: https://ssitools.com/helpandsuport/ssianalysishelp/_linked__subprojects_and_master_project.htm
